# How can I enumerate the transformation rules on lists of lists?

Tags: algorithms, pattern-matching

This is a question about pattern matching and list transformation rules.

(I may have the notation a bit wrong). Basically I'm thinking of rules which transform a set of balls with a letter on them, and the rules say what you must replace that letter with. So if you swap two letters on two balls then this doesn't count as no-transformation. Since we can line up the balls in any order to start with, so if 2 letters are swapped we would notice it. But the ordering you start with shouldn't matter. So in the following it might be better to think of them as lists in which we can randomize the order at the start.

The rules cannot refer to the position of the element in the list since the ordering can be randomized at the start.

Given a **list of lists** of characters of equal size. I want to enumerate all the possible list transformation rules.

For example, a set of rules could be:

$$\{A \rightarrow B, C \rightarrow D, E \rightarrow B, EverythingElse \rightarrow F\}$$

So that, for example, it transforms the lists:

$\{A,C,E,G\} \rightarrow \{B,D,B,F\}$ and $\{H,C,E,A\}\rightarrow \{F,D,B,B\}$

So I've managed to think up **5 cases** so far:

**CASE 1** - *Replace the remainders*

Normal rules for most elements, and then all other elements (which could be any number) which don't have a rule transform to a certain letter:

$$\{A_1 \rightarrow B_1, A_2 \rightarrow B_2, ..., AllOtherElements(\neq A_n) \rightarrow C\}$$

In other words it matches on the symbols from the first rules and then uses the last rule on everything it doesn't match. Because the lists are unordered it can only do the same thing to all of them (except in a special case).

e.g. $\{A_2,F,G,A_1\} \rightarrow \{B_2,C,C,B_1\}$

**CASE 2** - *The "swap"*

Normal rules for most elements, and then swap the final two left over elements whatever they may be:

$$\{A_1 \rightarrow B_1, A_2 \rightarrow B_2, ..., OtherX \rightarrow OtherY, OtherY\rightarrow OtherX\}$$

e.g. $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,C,D\}\rightarrow\{B_1,B_2,B_3,D,C\}$ and $\{E,F,A_2,A_3,A_1\}\rightarrow\{F,E,B_2,B_3,B_1\}$

**CASE 3** - *Use the remainder to transform other letters.*

Normal rules for most elements, and then the other element (X) goes to a certain letter. And Some other letters go to the other element (X). (The OtherElementX can be a different letter in each list.)

$$\{A_1 \rightarrow B_1, A_2 \rightarrow B_2, ..., OtherElementX(\neq A_n,D_n) \rightarrow C, D_1\rightarrow OtherElementX, D_2\rightarrow OtherElementX,...\}$$

e.g. $\{A_1,A_2,D_1,D_2,F\}\rightarrow \{B_1,B_2,F,F,C\}$

**CASE 4** - *Use the remainder to transform other letters but leave remainder unchanged.*

Same as case 3 except we don't transform the remainder.

$$\{A_1 \rightarrow B_1, A_2 \rightarrow B_2, ..., OtherElementX(\neq A_n,D_n) \rightarrow OtherElementX, D_1\rightarrow OtherElementX, D_2\rightarrow OtherElementX,...\}$$

e.g. $\{A_1,A_2,D_1,D_2,F\}\rightarrow \{B_1,B_2,F,F,F\}$

**CASE 5** - *Leave the rest alone*

Normal rules for most elements, and then just leave the remaining elements how they are:

$$\{A_1 \rightarrow B_1, A_2 \rightarrow B_2, ..., OtherX \rightarrow OtherX, OtherY\rightarrow OtherY,...\}$$

e.g. $\{C,D,A_1,A_2\}\rightarrow \{C,D,B_1,B_2\}$

I think this is all the cases since something involving permutations of 3 or more left-over elements would involve pattern matching on 3 elements of the list and this can be done in two many ways.

**The question is:**

Are these the only possible rules on lists? (Can it be proved?) Is there a better notation for this?

**Background**

The background for this question is from IQ tests where you are given a list of lists and asked to find a transformation rule. So I think all transformation rules must be from one of these 3 cases.

Comment: I don't understand several things about this question. What is the significance of the lists here? All the examples you describe are just transformations on individual letters, so aren't you just asking about arbitrary functions from a set of letters to itself?

Comment: @Qiaochu. No because the transformation from [A,B]->[B,A] which is the swap transformation would not be a transformation at all if it was a set. Whereas if you had a picture of two colors A and B and you swapped the colors B and A that would look different. But the rules only refer to the colors but not the position of the thing in the picture in this case. This rule would be like saying "swap the colors in the picture" (if the picture had just 2 colors)

Comment: Also, the lists are important because the "OtherElement" refers to the element in the list which doesn't have a transformation rule. e.g. you might have 3 pictures all with red and green and one other color (which colour be different in each picture). Then your rule might be "change the other color (not red or green) to blue".

Comment: I really still don't understand what you're asking. Do you have any examples of these IQ test questions you can link to? Can you tell me every rule that satisfies your conditions in the case of $2$ letters $\{ A, B \}$ or three letters $\{ A, B, C \}$?

Comment: Here's an example. What is the transformation rule for these pairs: [A,B,C]->[D,C,B],  [E,F,A]->[F,E,D],  and [ X,A,Y] ->[Y,D,X].   Which case is this?

Comment: Haven't you just swapped around the pairs $(B, C), (A, D), (E, F), (X, Y)$? Didn't you just say that wasn't allowed?

Comment: No, this is case 3. Since the rule is {A->D, OtherX->OtherY, OtherY->OtherX}. In other words A->D and swap the remaining ones.

Comment: I really cannot understand you at all, and in particular I still don't understand the significance or insignificance of the ordering of the lists. Please find another way of describing the problem.

Comment: That's alright you don't have to answer the question. The ordering is thus: the transformation rule that takes [A,B,C]->[D,E,F] is the same one that takes [B,C,A]->[E,F,D]. Thus we can permute both input and output and the rule will still work. All 3 cases will work if we permute both inputs and outputs in the same way. e.g. a rule that swaps a pair of elements [A,B]->[B,A] for example, is invariant if we permute both inputs and outputs to [B,A]->[A,B]. This rule is called "swap the pair of elements"

Comment: However a rule that is banned is "permute 3 elements in a list cyclically" because this rule is not invariant under permutaitons of  elements in input/output pairs. Because it depends on the ordering of the elements in the list.